# Restrict facebook app from accessing user's friends list

Tags: facebook

I am using facebook to login to my website. The website does not need any information about the facebook user's friends' list. I am interested only in the user's general information.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/public-profile-and-friend-list/ shows the friend list also as the minimum information shared by Facebook.

Hence wanted to check if there is any way to restrict the user friend list information from being passed on from facebook to my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, when a user authorize an application the minimum data shared is it's basic information and friend list.

Unfortunately you cannot change this.

Official documentation:

> When someone connects with an app using Facebook Login, the app can
>   access their **public profile and friend list**, the pieces of information
>   that are visible to everyone. Each other piece of information that
>   someone adds to their Facebook profile is secured behind permissions.

[Source: Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/)

Comment: yep, that is my understanding as well.